# Using Geography with NHibernate.Spatial in Asp.net Web.Api project

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api2, nhibernate-mapping, geography

I am using NHibernate in Web.Api project and started implementing logic for geo data processing. I am following an article [Spatial](http://nhibernate.info/doc/spatial/configuration-and-mapping.html) from Nhibernate but something goes wrong with my configuration. I don't understand why. My configuration section:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
  <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
  <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string_name">DefaultConnection</property>
  <!--<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>-->
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Spatial.Dialect.MsSql2008GeographyDialect,NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="command_timeout">120</property>
  <mapping assembly="GeoMail.Core" />
</session-factory>
```

Property in class:

```
public virtual NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point Geo { get; set; }
```

and it's mapping:

```
<property name="Geo" column="geo" >
  <type name="NHibernate.Spatial.Type.GeometryType, NHibernate.Spatial">
    <param name="srid">4326</param>
    <param name="subtype">POINT</param>
  </type>
</property>
```

extra configuration:

```
 private void InitSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration().Configure();
        cfg.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject( new SpatialAuxiliaryDatabaseObject( cfg ) );
        Metadata.AddMapping( cfg, MetadataClass.GeometryColumn );
        Metadata.AddMapping( cfg, MetadataClass.SpatialReferenceSystem );

        sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

but I always get this error:
Resource not found: **NHibernate.Spatial.Metadata.SpatialReferenceSystem.MsSql2008GeographyDialect.hbm.xml**
But!
Looking into an assembly we can find:
-       System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql").GetManifestResourceNames()
        **[0]   "NHibernate.Spatial.Metadata.GeometryColumn.MsSql2008GeographyDialect.hbm.xml"

        [1](http://nhibernate.info/doc/spatial/configuration-and-mapping.html) "NHibernate.Spatial.Metadata.GeometryColumn.MsSql2008GeometryDialect.hbm.xml"

        [2] "NHibernate.Spatial.Metadata.SpatialReferenceSystem.MsSqlLegacyDialect.hbm.xml" 
        [3] "NHibernate.Spatial.Metadata.GeometryColumn.MsSqlLegacyDialect.hbm.xml"**

Why the library is looking for missing resource?

If not to add mapping MetadataClass.SpatialReferenceSystem property Geo always returns null.
installed packages:

```
 <package id="GeoAPI" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.0.4000" targetFramework="net45" /> 
 <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />     
 <package id="NetTopologySuite" version="1.13.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="NetTopologySuite.IO" version="1.13.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="NHibernate" version="4.0.0.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql" version="4.0.3.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

While I didn't use Spatial namespace and dialect project went well. But now I don't know what to do....

Comment: just an idea but maybe you have the wrong version? it seems to require MsSql2008

Comment: NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql currently contains MsSql2008GeographyDialect.... or you means different place for version?

Comment: just added SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies( Server.MapPath( "~/bin" ) ); but it doesn't help. If not to call Metadata.AddMapping( cfg, MetadataClass.SpatialReferenceSystem ); exception doesn't appear but Geo property returns always null

Comment: Ok but did you add the correct library to your project? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: yes. I use VS 2013. Library seems to be correct

Comment: can you send me the project somewhere?

Comment: on GitHub https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.Spatial/blob/master/NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql/NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql.csproj MsSql2008GeographyDialect.hbm.xml is included... but exception throws

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86691/discussion-between-verena-haunschmid-and-andriy).